# How to route incoming call to queue of agents though AGI C Program in Asterisk

Tags: c, asterisk, sip, asteriskami, agi

I am using AGI in C Language for a basic Call Centre Setup in Asterisk

```
[PUNDIT]
exten =>92186,1,agi(Pundit/PunditBin)
exten=>92186,2,Hangup
```

PunditBin is a C application. On receiving the call the app dail Agent SIP URI directly and it works (Agent Phone Rings).

```
fprintf(stdout,"EXEC Dial SIP/%s,50\n",Free_Pundit);
```

But the problem is that i have to include the ACD logic in the app itself. However, I want to use Asterisk Queue and ACD mechanism.

I have configured the Asterisk ACD in following manner:-

```
**queues.conf:-**

[exchat_pundit]
musicclass=default       ; play [default] music
strategy=rrmemory        ; use the Round Robin Memory strategy
joinempty=no             ; do not join the queue when no members available
leavewhenempty=yes       ; leave the queue when no members available
ringinuse=no             ; don't ring members when already InUse (prevents
context=QueueMemberFunctions

**Extension.conf**
//Moving the call to Queue of agents
[Queues]
exten => 7001,1,Verbose(2,${CALLERID(all)} entering the chat Pundit queue)
same => n,Queue(exchat_pundit)
same => n,Hangup()



[LocalSets]
include => Queues      ; allow phones to call queues

//Agent Registration, Pause etc..
[QueueMemberFunctions]

exten => *54,1,Verbose(2,Logging In Queue Member)
   same => n,Set(MemberChannel=${CHANNEL(channeltype)}/${CHANNEL(peername)})
   same => n,AddQueueMember(exchat_pundit,${MemberChannel})

; ${AQMSTATUS}
;   ADDED
;   MEMBERALREADY
;   NOSUCHQUEUE

exten => *56,1,Verbose(2,Logging Out Queue Member)
   same => n,Set(MemberChannel=${CHANNEL(channeltype)}/${CHANNEL(peername)})
   same => n,RemoveQueueMember(exchat_pundit,${MemberChannel})

; ${RQMSTATUS}:
;    REMOVED
;    NOTINQUEUE
;    NOSUCHQUEUE

exten => *72,1,Verbose(2,Pause Queue Member)
   same => n,Set(MemberChannel=${CHANNEL(channeltype)}/${CHANNEL(peername)})
   same => n,PauseQueueMember(exchat_pundit,${MemberChannel})

; ${PQMSTATUS}:
;     PAUSED
;     NOTFOUND

exten => *87,1,Verbose(2,Unpause Queue Member)
   same => n,Set(MemberChannel=${CHANNEL(channeltype)}/${CHANNEL(peername)})
   same => n,UnpauseQueueMember(exchat_pundit,${MemberChannel})

; ${UPQMSTATUS}:
;     UNPAUSED
;     NOTFOUND


**Sip.conf:-**

//Agents 
[ABC]
type=friend; 'user' takes incoming calls
secret=welcome ; password for authenticating the user
nat=yes
disallow=all ; Disallow all codecs for this peer or user definition.
allow=speex
allow=gsm
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw
host=dynamic ; what kind of host you are dealing with and the value .dynamic.
context=QueueMemberFunctions; this is what ties up the Asterisk SIP user with the dialplan in
username=ABC; this field specifies the user name for authentication.
regexten=ABC;


[XYZ]
type=friend; 'user' takes incoming calls
secret=welcome ; password for authenticating the user
disallow=all ; Disallow all codecs for this peer or user definition.
allow=speex
allow=gsm
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw
host=dynamic 
context=QueueMemberFunctions
username=XYZ; 
regexten=XYZ;
```

Now when i make a call to extension 7001 using a sip phone directly, my call is sent to the agent in round robin manner it works per fine.

Problem is when i dial the extension 7001 from my C code as following, it does not work.

```
fprintf(stdout,"EXEC Dial 7001,50\n");
```

I am not able to send the incoming call to queue of agents.

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Regards,
Raghuvendra Kumar

Answer (score 2):

You can use dial with Local channel to dialplan like this

```
Dial(Local/7001@Queues,,n)
```

or in AGI

```
fprintf(stdout,"EXEC Dial \"Local/7001@Queues,50\"\n");
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thanks for the support. One more query,  If i want to do the same thing in with AMI do i need to use bridge action:- api.BridgeAction bc= new BridgeAction(A-Party-Channel, B-Party-Channel, false) - for connecting party. How to connect to the queue using AMI

Comment: If you use dial command, it will bridge automaticaly on answer. Otherwise - depend of method. Use channelredirect to redirect other dialplan extension(including queue)